# Ext js how to check if the user is approver or not IN EXT JS

Tags: json, extjs6

```
                 {
                      var IndentGrid = function () {
                       };
                      IndentGrid.prototype = {
                      getIndentGridPanel: function (_empID) {

                      Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                      storeId: 'RequestStore1',
                      displayInfo: true,
                      fields: [
                              {name: 'INDENT NO', mapping: 'INDENTNO'},
                              {name: 'ITEM DESCRIPTION', mapping: 'INDENTSHORTDES'},
                              {name: 'INDENT DATE', mapping: 'INDENTDATE'},
                              {name: 'LINEITEMCODE', mapping: 'LINEITEMCODE'},
                              {name: 'TOTAL COST', mapping: 'TOTALINDCOST'},
                              {name: 'CURRENT STATUS OF INDENT', mapping: 'PURCHASESTATUS'},
                     ],
                proxy: {
                  type: 'ajax',
                  url: 'IndentGridServlet',
                  extraParams: {
                empid: _empID,
                indentdate:''

            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'indents',
                totalProperty: 'count'
            }
        }, autoLoad: true,
        listeners: {
            callback: function (store, record, success, opts) {
                var response_text = store.proxy.reader.rawData;
                console.log(response_text);
            }
        }

    });
       
    }
```

MY JSON DATA
how to check if the user is approver or not using the JSON data in EXT JS .
iam new to Ext js .
here what type of validation is required to check if the user is approver or not already in json
data iam capturing the if the user is appover or not but how to implement in the Ext js .
how to validate or check if the user is approver.
please help me out .
approver iam checking out if the user is aprover or not in json format iam sending the data. approver is in boolean format. is th approver is true how to check and validate in ext js .
i have called a servlet where it contains all the data of the employee.
but if the employee is approver employee or not is becoming difficult for me .
myjson data contains the approver and employee info like date of birth , division
code,employeecode,employeename.
how to get the validate in ext js using that json data .
below is the Json data :

{"approver":true,"employee":{"DATEOFBIRTH":"1974-06-01 00:00:00.0","DIVNCODE":"YTUIOP","EMPLOYEECODE":"GH13467","DESGCODE":"1107","EMPLOYEENAME":"XYZ"}}

Can anyone help me out as soon as possible.